# How to configure flutter ffmpeg

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, flutter-dependencies, android-ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I am developing a flutter app with flutter_ffmpeg package , I want to compress video and using this function

FFmpeg.execute('-i input.mp4 -c:v lib*264 crf 0 output.mp4')

Now , the ffmpeg is saying unrecognised option CRF after removing it , it says unknown encoder lib*264

After googling , I found that I have to --enable-lib*264

How to enable it? In flutter ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on video compression with `ffmpeg_kit_flutter` I came across that error.

Switching from `ffmpeg_kit_flutter` to  `ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl: ^5.1.0` fixed it for me,